# Extract XML information to text

Tags: c#

I have the following .xml which is formatted as such;

```
<imgdir name="Map.img">
  <imgdir name="3rd">
    <imgdir name="300000000">
      <string name="streetName" value="Ellin Forest" />
      <string name="mapName" value="Altaire Camp" />
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="300000100">
      <string name="streetName" value="Altaire Camp" />
      <string name="mapName" value="Small Forest" />
    </imgdir>
  </imgdir>
 <imgdir name="MasteriaGL">
   <imgdir name="610030010">
     <string name="streetName" value="Crimsonwood  Keep" />
     <string name="mapName" value="Hall of Mastery" />
   </imgdir>
```

I need a c# console to go through each imgdir name, "3rd", "MasteriaGL", etc (there are many more names), and to give the output as such;

```
ID: 300000000 NAME: 3rd : Ellin Forest : Altaire Camp
ID: 300000100 NAME: 3rd : Altaire Camp : Small Forest
ID: 610030010 NAME: MasteriaGL : Crimsonwood  Keep : Hall of Mastery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    private static string GetString(XmlNode root)
    {
        string retStr = "";

        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("imgdir");

        if (nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                retStr=retStr+"\r\n"+GetString(node);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string street = root.SelectSingleNode("string[@name='streetName']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string map = root.SelectSingleNode("string[@name='mapName']").Attributes["value"].Value;
            string id = root.Attributes["name"].Value;
            retStr ="ID " + id+":"+"NAME "+root.ParentNode.Attributes["name"].Value+":"+ street + ":" + map;
        }
        return retStr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Stack.xml");

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("imgdir/imgdir");

        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(GetString(node));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: this crashes me, system.nullreferenceexception: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user3602826. Can you say the line number? Generally it means that there is no node with this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can read `XML` for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Home>
  <TextEntries>
  <follow>
      <item visible="true" navid="fb" url="https://www.facebook.com/" type="text" hideineditor="false" esbname="facebook  Follow Link" linktype="new" id="200038"><![CDATA[facebook]]></item>
      <item visible="true" navid="twitter" url="https://twitter.com/" type="text" hideineditor="false" esbname="twitter  Follow Link" linktype="new" id="200039"><![CDATA[twitter]]></item>
   </follow>
 </TextEntries>
</Home>
```

**Reading Nodes:**

```
  XmlElement root = null;
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(sourceXmlFilePath);
  root = doc.DocumentElement;
  XmlNode rootnode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Home//TextEntries");
  XmlNode followNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Home//TextEntries//follow");
  string myAttribute=followNode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["id"].Value;//this will read the attribute ID of first inner element
 string myFirstInnerNodeValue=followNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;//this will read the data of first inner node i.e facebook
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `<imgdir name="Map.img">` is the root element of your actual XML, you can do this way :

```
var file = XElement.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var secondLevelImgdirs = file.Elements("imgdir");
foreach(var imgDir2 in secondLevelImgdirs)
{
    var name = (string)imgDir2.Attribute("name");
    var thirdLevelImgdirs = imgDir2.Elements("imgdir");
    foreach(var imgDir3 in thirdLevelImgdirs)
    {
        var id = (string)imgDir3.Attribute("name");
        var streetName = (string)imgDir3.Elements("string")
                                        .FirstOrDefault(o => "streetName" == (string)o.Attribute("name"));
        var mapName = (string)imgDir3.Elements("string")
                                     .FirstOrDefault(o => "mapName" == (string)o.Attribute("name"));

        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} NAME: {1} : {2} : {3}", id, name, streetName, mapName);
    }
}
```